# Connecting a Nexus 7 (2013) to a VGA projector

Tags: nexus-7, external-display

I would like to connect my Nexus 7 (2013)  to an external projector or monitor. I know that there is a SlimPort to HDMI adapter (I have it and it works when plugged through HDMI), however, projectors at my work still have VGA (and no HDMI) socket.

In addition to the SlimPort HDMI adapter by Analogix, I also bought an HDMI to VGA adapter. The problem is that the external displays do not display any content (the SlimPort to HDMI cable is working, though). I also saw a SlimPort to VGA adapter from Analogix, but apparently it did not work either.

Has anyone succeeded in connecting the Nexus 7 (2013) to a VGA display? Even with complicated or costly systems.

I was wondering if something like that could work:
http://www.miniinthebox.com/hd-video-hdmi-to-vga-scaler-converter-box-black_p296227.html

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a laptop with USB ports that can also connect to the VGA projector, then you can use Droid@Screen (http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com) to show the Nexus' display on the laptop and in turn, on the projector.

Depending on what you are doing, this might work while you figure out a more robust solution. I say this because the main downside is lag, so it's not a good solution if you are trying to project video or show off a new buttery interface.